# Iniitalize a union in a struct with a specific memberi in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization, unions

I know there are a lot of articles over here about this topic, but anyone of them didn't work for me.

The problem comes from converting c source to c++ source.

I have a struct.

```
typedef struct OptionDef {
    const char *name;
    int flags;
    union {
        void *dst_ptr;
        size_t off;
    } u;
} OptionDef;
```

And what I want to is that

```
int main() {
    const OptionDef optoins[] = {
       { "f", HAS_ARG/*SOME DEFINED VALUE*/, { .off = 2 } }
       { "c", OPT_STRING, { .off = 3} }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But in c++, an error occures "expected an expression".
How can I initialize "off" member of union?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not Options, is OptionDef.

Comment: Don't paraphrase error messages. Copy them exactly.

Comment: I quoted the error message.

Comment: This is what my compiler says: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cedebcb5396c8b2

Comment: I checked this, but not help. can you explain about that?